# Assign macro-list is empty

Tags: excel

Windows10, Office 2019 Home and Student (Version 2111), Excel. Fully updated.

When I try to assign a macro to a button in a worksheet, the drop-down list is empty. It should be more than 1000 macros to choose from.

I still have all macros in the VBA editor, VBAProject(Personal.XLSB) and they are still working when clicking buttons in worksheets.
Personal.xlsb file is 10080 kb. I reduced it to 9900 kb (removed old macros) if maybe 10000 kb was a limit, but that didn't help.

My largest macro is 42 kb and all are "Option Explicit".
One thing I recently learned from a website, is to "Compile" VBAProject in VBA Editor (Debug/Compile). I did so and had to change or remove about 30 macros.
Maybe this problem started after that.

I have run Office online repair, uninstalled Office with Microsoft’s tool for complete removal (which I think is not quite true. It didn't remove "Personal.xlsb") and then installed Office 2019 Home and Student, online again. After that I deleted Personal.xlsb in Explorer, C:\Users"Username"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB.

I also read in another website how to create a new Personal.xlsb file. The advice was: click "Start recording" and immediately after that "Stop recording", without creating any code. I tried it but that didn't help. Again, after some testing, I uninstalled office and reinstalled it, and this time when I created the Personal.xlsb file I clicked "Start recording", created a simple macro and then clicked "Stop recording". Still not possible to assign macros to a button.

I wrote 2 new simple test macros. 1 in a workbook and 1 in Personal.xlsb. The macro in the workbook shows up under that workbook name, but not the other macro under Personal.xlsb, in the "Assign macro" drop-down list.

In short: Assigning new macro in a workbook works but assigning old and new macros in "Personal.xlsb" don't.

I have a 10 days old backup of Peronal.xlsb (copy/paste) and another backup of every macro (.bas), created with this line of code:
`objVBComp.Export "C:\users\"Username"\Documents\MacroCopies\" & objVBComp.Name & ".bas"`.

I can import "macroname".bas to Personal.xlsb and I can assign those imported (.bas) macros to a button in the worksheet. Problem is that I have more than 1000 macros and import one by one takes a lot of time.

I have had this problem 1 time before, maybe 2 years ago. As I remember it, I reinstalled Office, created a new Personal.xlsb, restarted PC, copied my backup of Personal.xlsb and pasted it in XLSTART and everything was ok.

Is there a way to import multiple "macroname".bas -files to Personal.xlsb?
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try File - Options - AddIns, select 'Disabled Items' in the Manage list, then click Go. See if Personal.xlsb appears in the list. If so, enable it.

Comment: Thanks Rory, for your quick reply. I checked and the list is empty. Also no Excel and COM Add-ins are activated.

Comment: I can't remember if this is in 2019, but see if in the Macro settings in the trust center, there is an option relating to Excel4 macros.

Comment: Nothing about Excel4 macros there. "Disable all macros with notification" and "Trust access to the VBA project object model" are ticked.

Comment: @Rory I have noticed something strange with Personal.xlsb. 2021-12-20 08:25, backup is 5961 kb. 21-12-20 16:03 backup is 10080 kb. I have not imported any macros that day. Today I reinstalled Office, created a new Personal.xlsb and copied the smaller one to Excel\START. Still have the same problem.

Comment: There are two XLSTART folders so make sure you don't have a personal macro workbook in both (also check any other folder designated as a startup folder in Excel's options)

Comment: @Rory Thank you for your efforts to try to help me. I only have one Personal.xlsb in my PC. Last week I imported 200 macros, one by one and all of them was visible in the drop-down list. After that I wanted to backup them as .bas but my code didn't work. I checked a workbook and also the drop-down list was empty again. My solution: go into the VBA Editor and Select the Tools Menu and References then search for Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5 and tick the box. After that I can run the code and the macros are visible in the drop-down list again.